# Aligning Multiple Tables Horizontally using CSS or HTML for IE lower versions(6,7,8)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My code works fine for IE 10 and higher version, as well as in Chrome and Firefox.
But Users basically use either low version of IE. Apart from that, most of the code that is built for the lower version of IEs. hence even with IE 10, they have to use compatibility mode.
I need to align multiple tables side by side.
I am generating HTML tables using code. So its same table in a control used multiple times in a web page.

In IE10, chrome, firefox - Display property set as Inline-Block is working fine. However its not getting detected in compatibility mode.

Any suggestion will help.

Thanks

Given below is test code, only the content inside table changes.
I was unable to insert my DIV with the rest of the code. So I am placing parenthesis around main div block

{div id="scroll3" style="overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll; height:300px; white-space:nowrap;"}

```
    div style="width:auto;"
    table style="display:inline-block;">
    <tr>
    <td>
     <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/7.jpg" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table style=" width:500px; display:inline-block;">
    <tr>
    <td>

    <asp:Image ID="Image10" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/10.jpg" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:500px; display:inline-block;">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Image ID="Image8" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/8.jpg" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:500px;display:inline-block;">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Image ID="Image9" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/9.jpg" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:500px;display:inline-block;">
    <tr>
    <td>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Image ID="Image11" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/11.jpg" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:500px;display:inline-block;">
    <tr>
    <td >
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
     <table style="width:500px;display:inline-block;">
    <tr>
    <td>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Image ID="Image12" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/12.jpg" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
     <table style="width:500px;display:inline-block;">
    <tr>
    <td>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Image ID="Image13" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/13.jpg" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
     <table style="display:inline-block;">
    <tr>
    <td>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Image ID="Image14" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/14.jpg" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
     <table style="width:500px;display:inline-block;">
    <tr>
    <td>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Image ID="Image15" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/15.jpg" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Any code will help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline-block` is NOT a suitable `display` property for a table.

Use `inline-table` instead... for modern browsers.

For support with older ones, however, you may need to use `float:left`, or even nested tables (ewwww, I feel dirty for even suggesting that...) to make it work as far back as IE6.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I am facing issue with old browsers. And in IE 10 compatibility mode.

Comment: So use the "For support with older ones..." part of my answer.

Comment: I already tried Float:left. Table inside table, I was thinking about it. But because I iterate the table through code, I might have to look for a way to insert this table as separate row.

Comment: Niet - I am going to use the dirty code. Its working that way. Thanks for the suggestion :). Need some formatting and adjustments with scrollbars but thats not big deal. Thanks again.